Android Rear Camera is not showing stream
Why is it that in some mobile device, i can view the camera stream on both front and back but in some other only the front, the back I cannot. Sometimes, on some other devices, I cannot see both the front and rear camera feed. I am using the same browser, for all devices. If the camera stream is not showing, all I see is a black screen. I know that my both cameras are woking. I came across this website called webcamtests.com I can actually see both of my camera streams (kinda awesome actually I don't know how they did it). What I mean by devices is android devices. All of them are either android 11 or 13.
This is how I implement the javascript
let currentFacingMode = "environment"; // Default to rear camera

    function startVideo(src) {
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                {
                    video: {
                        facingMode: currentFacingMode
                    }
                }).then(function (stream) {
                let video = document.getElementById(src);
                if ("srcObject" in video) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }
                video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
                    video.play();
                };
                //mirror image
                video.style.webkitTransform = "scaleX(-1)";
                video.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error accessing camera: ", error);
                    alert("Camera not accessible. Please check permissions and ensure the device supports the requested facing mode.");
                });;
        }
    }
    
    function toggleCamera() {
        debugger;
        if (currentFacingMode === "user") {
            debugger;
            currentFacingMode = "environment";
        } else {
            debugger;
            currentFacingMode = "user";
        }
        stopVideo("videoFeed");
        startVideo("videoFeed");
    }
    
    function getFrame(src, dest, dotNetHelper) {
        let video = document.getElementById(src);
        let canvas = document.getElementById(dest);
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
    
        let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('ProcessImage', dataUrl);
    }
    
    function stopVideo(src) {
        let video = document.getElementById(src);
        if (video && "srcObject" in video) {
            const stream = video.srcObject;
            if (stream) {
                const tracks = stream.getTracks();
                tracks.forEach(track => {
                    track.stop();
                    track.enabled = false;
                });
                stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                    if (track.readyState == 'live' && track.kind === 'video') {
                        track.stop();
                    }
                });
            }
            video.srcObject = null;
        }
    }


This is my component and code behind in Blazor
@using ITMS_Ver_2.Client.Services
@using ITMS_Ver_2.Shared._Entities
@using SixLabors.Fonts
@using SixLabors.ImageSharp
@using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing
@using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing.Processing
@using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
@using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg
@using SixLabors.Fonts
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.IO

<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex justify-center p-3">
            <video id="videoFeed" width="320" height="240" />
            <canvas class="d-none" id="currentFrame" width="320" height="240" />
        </MudPaper>

    </MudItem>

    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex justify-center p-3 align-center">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="captionText"
                          Label="Description"
                          Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                          Adornment="Adornment.Start"
                          AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Image"
                          AdornmentColor="MudBlazor.Color.Default"
                          Margin="Margin.Dense"
                          InputType="InputType.Text" />
        </MudPaper>
        
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
<br />
<MudPaper Class="d-flex justify-content-end p-2" Elevation="0">
    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined"
               StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Camera"
               IconColor="MudBlazor.Color.Default"
               Color="MudBlazor.Color.Primary"
               FullWidth="false"
               OnClick="CaptureFrame">Take Image</MudButton>

    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined"
               StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Camera"
               IconColor="MudBlazor.Color.Default"
               Color="MudBlazor.Color.Primary"
               FullWidth="false"
               OnClick="ToggleCamera">Switch</MudButton>
</MudPaper>

<br />

@if (ImageList != null && ImageList.Any())
{
    foreach (var item in ImageList)
    {
        <MudImage Src="@item.ImageString" ObjectFit="ObjectFit.Cover" 
            Width="95" Height="88"  
            Alt="image taken" 
            Elevation="25" 
            Class="rounded-lg m-1" />
    }
}

@code {

    [Inject] private IJSRuntime? JsRuntime { get; set; }
    [Inject] private HttpClient? Http { get; set; }
    [Inject] private ICommonService? CommonService { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? IncidentId { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public List<IncidentImage>? ImageList { get; set; }

    private string captionText;
    private string frameUri;

    FontCollection collection = new FontCollection();
    FontFamily sansFamily;
    Font captionFont;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await StartCamera();
    }

    private async Task StartCamera()
    {
        await JsRuntime!.InvokeVoidAsync("startVideo", "videoFeed");

        //Font stored in wwwroot. Fetch it as byte array, and use it
        var fontBytes = await Http!.GetByteArrayAsync("OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        collection.Install(new MemoryStream(fontBytes));
        collection.TryFind("Open Sans", out sansFamily);
        captionFont = sansFamily.CreateFont(16, FontStyle.Regular);
    }

    private async Task ToggleCamera()
    {
        await JsRuntime!.InvokeVoidAsync("toggleCamera");
    }

    private async Task CaptureFrame()
    {
        await JsRuntime!.InvokeAsync<String>("getFrame", "videoFeed", "currentFrame", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void ProcessImage(string imageString)
    {
        byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString.Split(',')[1]);

        DrawingOptions alignCenter = new DrawingOptions()
            {
                TextOptions = new TextOptions()
                {
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                    WrapTextWidth = 304, //Image is 320px wide. This centers with 8px margin on left and right
                    HorizontalAlignment = SixLabors.Fonts.HorizontalAlignment.Center
                }
            };

        using (var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(imageData))
        {
            image.Mutate(x => x
                .Flip(FlipMode.Horizontal) //To match mirrored webcam image
                .Fill(SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color.ParseHex("0008"), new RectangularPolygon(0, 220, 320, 20)) //Setting footer bar for caption
                .DrawText(alignCenter, captionText, captionFont, SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color.White, new PointF(8, 230)) //Centering in footer bar)
            );
            frameUri = image.ToBase64String(JpegFormat.Instance);
            var incidentImage = new IncidentImage
                {
                    IncidentId = IncidentId,
                    Description = captionText,
                    ImageString = frameUri,
                    TimeTaken = DateTime.Now,
                    FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        };
            if (ImageList == null)
            {
                ImageList = new();
                ImageList.Add(incidentImage);
            }
            else
            {
                ImageList.Add(incidentImage);
            }
            captionText = String.Empty;
            StartCamera();
        }
    }
}


If I use my laptop, i don't get any issues with the camera since it only has 1 camera and that's the one facing me. The problem occurs when I browse the website using an android device. with a front and rear camera. On the device, I can actually make the front camera work. But when I switch to the back camera, it doesn't work.
That is my complete js file. there is no more. The reason it looks incomplete is because I am using Blazor WASM. I just invoke this js functions in my components. Please see my Edit to see the whole program.
